# calling a method using data-target attribute in angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to display login modal if and only if the user is not logged in. If it is logged in I want only to call 'logout()' method using data attribute like

```
 [attr.data-target]="_service.login?'logout()':'#loginModal'"
```

But, the problem in the above code is the 'logout()' function shows me syntax error in the console window while the '#loginModal' works fine. So, how can I call the 'logout()' method using data-target attribute?

```
//html
  <input type="button" [value] = "_service.login? 'logout':'login'" 
[attr.data-target]="_service.login?'logout()':'#loginModal'" 
   data-toggle="modal">



 //component
  logout(){
    this._service.login = false;
  }
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting ? Also show us some more code to understand the exact scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logout() shouldn't be given as a string
try this:

```
<input type="button" [value] = "_service.login? 'logout':'login'" 
[attr.data-target]="_service.login ? logout():'#loginModal'" 
   data-toggle="modal">
```

and also a better way of doing this would be to use a structural directive like ngIf on your modal and use click listener on the button like:

```
<input type="button" [value] = "_service.login? 'logout':'login'" (click)="onToggle()" data-toggle="modal">
```

Modal HTML:

```
<yourModal *ngIf="_service.login" ></yourModal>
```

in your component.ts:

```
onToggle() {
 add your logic for login and logout here
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. But I get this error after the button value changed to logout   ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'value: logout'. Current value: 'value: login'.

Comment: That error occurs when we're incorrectly changing the template expression. See [this](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put _service.login inside '' and remove single quote from logout() method

```
 <input type="button" [attr.data-target]="'_service.login'?logout():'#loginModal'" data-toggle="modal">
```

I have checked it its working fine.